# GridView,New Row,Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, row

I have created a grid view which gets buttons dynamically on the footer.but needed for every row when I have click on 1 button i have 2 buttons on the footer.on button 1 click new row gets added.

But along with new row need another row which has buttons.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvCharacter" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="grvCharacter_RowCommand"
    CellPadding="1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnRowDeleting="grvCharacter_RowDeleting"
    Width="70%" Style="text-align: left">
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Type" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Person Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                    ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Style="align-content:center" runat="server" ID="lnkView" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CommandName="VIEW" >Add</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMovie" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMovie"
                    ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddSeq" runat="server" ToolTip="Add movie prequel or sequel" Text="Add Sequel/Prequel" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddReb" runat="server" ToolTip="Add another movie with same charecter" Text="Add Reboot" OnClick="ButtonAddReb_Click" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a button for adding new rows in your footer template in your GridView. This might not be the exact solution as per your requirement, should give you an idea in your direction though. You can try something like this :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
     <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
       <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" 
              onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
       </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

And next, you can handle the `OnClick` event for this button to add a new row everytime this button is clicked. This will maintain the state of the data in the gridview and add a new row at the bottom while also keeping the footer template as it is. You can try something like this in your code-behind file :

For setting the initial row and headers of your GridView :

```
private void SetInitialRow()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
    }
```

For adding a new row everytime footer button is clicked :

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtProduct");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtQuantity");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                //add new row to DataTable
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
```

For setting the previous data in the GridView after a new row is added :

```
private void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtProduct");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtQuantity");

                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    rowIndex++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is already done in my code.but my query is when i click on say "ButtonAddReb" button in my grid i should able to populate new row with text boxes and another row with those two buttons. but when i click "ButtonAddSeq" button i need not populate those two buttons and should get only text boxes in my next row.

Comment: By saying adding another row with those two buttons, if you mean to say the footer buttons, then that is covered in the above solution. You would just have to modify this around a bit and you'll get it.

Comment: I have 2 action buttons, on clicking the first a new row with text boxes are to be added, <thats happening> on clicking the second, the above mentioned row with text boxes should be formed along with the 2 buttons replicating in the next row, keeping the entire set of text boxes and buttons in tact above. this is what I need help with